# Updating textbox.text value when executing code

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

If i use: `Label1.Invoke(Sub() Label1.Text = "Test")` this updates successfully however, if i try do: `Txt_Response.Invoke(Sub() Txt_Response.Text = "Test")` the text only updates after the rest of the code has executed and the thread is free.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this without any extra load?

Comment: I'm not seeing that behaviour.  In my test, both controls reflected the change when it was made.  I just had a `Thread.Sleep` call before and after the invocations.  What else are you doing?

Comment: Control.Invoke() in synchronous. If it doesn't raise an exception, then the request has been fulfilled and the control's property has been updated. It doesn't mean that the UI had the chance to re-drawn itself. Try with BeginInvoke(), the asynchronous version (which also works when the thread is actually the same thread where the code is executed).

Comment: I am running a bunch of other operations for connecting to a COM Port and pushing commands down the pipe. So my aim was to show progress of everything as its doing all that. Seemed to have failed doing the easy way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt want to do the long way but i guess i needed it done!

Basically the fix is below, i have added the ability to provide controls so its dynamic to everything but for the sake of this question, i will provide it for textbox.

```
Private Delegate Sub ResponseUpdateEventHandler(ByVal message As String)
    Private Sub UpdateResponseBox(ByVal message As String)
        If Txt_Response.InvokeRequired Then
            Txt_Response.Invoke(New ResponseUpdateEventHandler(AddressOf UpdateResponseBox), New Object() {message})
        Else
            Txt_Response.AppendText(message + Environment.NewLine)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Then just call using: `UpdateResponseBox("Connecting to device, Please wait...")`